# Why CSS color var(--indigo) doesn't work with npm 14.18.0?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, deployment

I had on my project npm with verison `8.9.4` then I updated it to `14.18.0` and it works fine for me locally. But when I deployed my code on test environment I see that color doesn't work.

In code it looks like:

```
  color: var(--indigo)
```

With npm 8.9.4 in browser it looks like the same, but with npm 14.18.0 I see that in browser it looks like   `color: var(indigo);`. Why 2 dashes disappeared?

Also I have scss preprocessor on my project, but this color also use in simple css files and it doesn't work around the project.

Browser error:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdJy7.png)

Comment: I don't think the npm version is significant here, maybe the sass version or config. Can you show a screenshot from the browser devtools?

Comment: @skara9 added image to the post

Comment: If your code still contains has `color: var(--indigo)` then it seems that something in your css pipeline goes wrong.

Comment: @Thomas where I can see logs or how I can find out the problem? I use Jenkins for deploying

Comment: `npm` doesn't do changes - the dependencies or scripts it runs do change things. It must be you **scss preprocessor** that has changed too? I suspect that it is because the CSS variable name conflicts with the [W3C CSS color code](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-css1-960505.html#appendix-b) with the same name.

Comment: @RandyCasburn In my case with the same error, but with different color, your suspicion was the answer. Thanks! Can you post it as an answer please ? Hopefully solved it for the OP too.